# Instagram API feed only returns 16 posts

Tags: php, api, count, instagram

Today I started working with the Instagram API.
I got it working only with one problem.

Here is the code that I use:

```
    $value = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=mytokenhere');
    $value = json_decode($value, true);
    print_r($value)
```

My problem is that I want to get exactly 20 results yet I only manage to get exactly 16 of them. I tried a few things:

- The count parameter &count=20
- Checked if all the people on my feed aren't private
- Added a picture to Instagram, stays at 16.

I have no idea how I can fix this. When I say &count=5 it returns 4 and &count=10 gives 8..

Thanks in advance! Tips / help would be appreciated!

Edit: While reading this post through again I saw this:
Count 5 returns 4
Count 10 returns 8
Count 15 returns 12
Count 20 returns 16 .. For every 5 it just leaves one out.
I just tried 25 and it worked! I got returned with 20.

Still I think this is a problem! Or is this how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple http request using your url https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=mytokenhere&count=5
using any browser or curl on command line.

Then examine the response visually, it should be a json payload. You can pretty-print it with for example, http://jsonprettyprint.com/.

The big json payload should have some headers and a sub json array of data, this array should have 5 elements.

If the http request itself has no problem, then it might be some bug in the php functions you called, file_get_contents, print_r, and json_decode, or the way you are using them might be problematic.